# HTML and CSS solid bar or line behind (connecting) elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

I Jerry-rigged a line behind 3 elements by having bars on the right and left of the elements. However, this solution isn't consistent across browsers -- See images below.

Is there a better way to place a line centered behind several objects using HTML and CSS? I tried and failed using pseudo elements/selectors (i.e., `:after` or `:before`) before coming to my solution below, but I don't want to rule them out.

#### Chrome

[image]

#### IE

[image]

My solution is, in fact, so jerry-rigged that I can't reproduce it in JS fiddle, but I did something like this:

(My fiddle just for reference https://jsfiddle.net/8t6qtafy/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="tab-header">
    <span>
        <div class="header-bar bar-left bar-blank"></div>
        <p>1</p>
        <div class="header-bar bar-right"></div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div class="header-bar bar-left"></div>
        <p>2</p>
        <div class="header-bar bar-right"></div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div class="header-bar bar-left"></div>
        <p>3</p>
        <div class="header-bar bar-right bar-blank"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html {
  font-family: calibri;
}
.container {
  width = 400px;
  margin:auto;
}
.tab-header {
    margin-top:10px;
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 10px;
    //display:inline-block;
}
.tab-header span {
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#4c4a47;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:2px solid #99958E;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.tab-header span p {
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    left:.5px;
    margin:2px;
}
.tab-header .header-bar {
    width:130px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#99958E;
    position:relative;
}

.tab-header .bar-right {
    left:42px;
    top:-36px;
}

.tab-header .bar-left {
    right:130px;
    top: 19px;
}

.tab-header .header-bar.bar-blank {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: All hail the good old Internet Explorer

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party: what browsers needed to be compatible?

Something like that is a bit neater and could work on all modern browsers and IE10: https://jsfiddle.net/fparent/qhprm41a

```
<div class="tab-header">
    <span class="step active">1</span>
    <span class="step">2</span>
    <span class="step">3</span>
</div>
```